# Created a tag with a typo, but can't change it (or suggest synonym)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I created a new tag for `C/AL` (Client/Server Application Language for Microsoft Dynamics NAV), which was recently approved. However, I just noticed that I have a typo. I am unable to suggest a synonym since I have yet to score 5 in the tag.

Can someone please fix the typo (or suggest the synonym)? Tag can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/93149).

The word *client* has been mispelled (*cllient*).

Comment: Done. All you needed to do was retag, I did it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on one question. It'd be simpler to create the tag with the appropriate spelling, copy the wiki and excerpt, apply it to the question, remove the misspelled tag, and wait for the misspelled tag to be auto-removed. It's not going to be very useful as a synonym.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have more questions I will be tagging with this, but I happened to notice the spelling mistake before doing any more. Thanks.